# no se pudo traducir. Vuelva a escribir la consulta en un formulario que se pueda traducir en Linq C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

Actualmente quiero hacer una consulta que obtenga información de 3 tablas diferentes y entre esas 3 tablas crear una relación para en base a eso poder obtener lo que requiero pero también necesito agrupar los productos por cada orden que se ha hecho y así obtener un listado de ordenes y un listado de productos dentro cada item de ordenes.

```
var ordenes = (from ord in myDbContext.orden
                             join prod_ord in myDbContext.prod_orden on ord.idOrden equals prod_ord.idOrden
                             join prod in myDbContext.producto on prod_ord.idProducto equals prod.idProducto
                             where ord.idCliente==clienteIdInt
                           group prod by new { prod,ord,prod_ord } into grp
                           select new 
                             {
                                 IdOrden = grp.Key.ord.idOrden,
                                 Codigo = grp.Key.ord.codigo,
                                 Comentarios = grp.Key.ord.Comentarios,
                                 Fecha = grp.Key.ord.fecha,
                                 Estatus = grp.Key.ord.Estatus,
                                 IdCliente = grp.Key.ord.idCliente,
                                 Prioridad = grp.Key.ord.Prioridad,
                                 Latitud = grp.Key.ord.Latitud,
                                 Longitud = grp.Key.ord.Longitud,
                                 IdDomicilio = grp.Key.ord.IdDomicilio,
                                 idSucursal = grp.Key.ord.IdSucursal,
                                 titulo = "titulo",
                                 producto =(from product in myDbContext.producto where grp.Key.prod_ord.idProducto==product.idProducto select product).ToList()
                             }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Fecha).ToList();
```

Pero me marca el siguiente error.

> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can
> be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting
> a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList'

Me gustaría saber qué parte de la consulta está mal o por qué surge ese problema.

Comment: Intenta comentando la línea de `producto = (from....`, también quitando la coma luego de `"titulo"`.

Comment: el groupby no tienes que poner prod.Propiedad, ord.Propiedad, prod_ord.Propiedad? No te falta la propiedad?